# jqplot gridline with data

Tags: jquery, charts, rendering, jqplot

hi i am using CategoryAxisRenderer for x axis in my graph x gridlines not showed with respect to data it will show after the data i am adding the picture in that a,12.0 ,  b,15.0,  c,18.0  x-gridline not showed in marker point

[image]

my code is below

```
     <div id="wind_cha" style="width:670px; height:350px;"></div>
<script>
      $.jqplot ('wind_cha', [[12,15,18]],
          {
           title: 'chart example',
           axesDefaults: {
                          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                          },
           seriesDefaults: {
                            showMarker:true,
                            pointLabels: { show:true }
                           },
                 axes: {
                        xaxis: {
                                label: 'x label',
                               renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                               rendererOptions:{sortMergedLabels:true},
                               ticks : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                               pad:2
                             },
                         yaxis: {
                                 label: 'test',
                                 ticks : ['0','5','10','15','20','25','30','35'],
                               tickOptions:{
                                           formatString: '%#.2f'
                                            }                             
                                         }
                                    }
                                });
              </script>
```

Please guide me to draw x-gridline with respect to data